# How to access Angular JS custom filter JSON data in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing multi language support Angular JS project. I want to translate label names into a specific language (Label names - search sites, visit site. It is already have values). For this I'm not using Angular JS translate. I'm gonna write a new custom filter. ( What I planned is to have label name values in different languages in a seperate json file.)

App Filter

```
app.filter('langTrans', function() {
//Instead of reading values, I only added demo values to test.
var data ={"searchsites":"recherche ", "visitsite":"voir "}

return function(data) {
    //custom filter translation logic goes here

    return "//value goes here ";

}  });
```

In my view , I have called filter using a pipe. But instead of retriving all values , I only need to return the value of specific element (Ex: for first button I only need to retrieve search site translated value)

```
 <li>
  <md-button ng-href="#!/search">{{searchsites | langTrans}}</md-button>
</li>
<li>
  <md-button ng-href="#!/visit">{{ visitsite | langTrans }}</md-button>
</li>
```

Comment: what `searchsites` & `visitsite` has?

Comment: It has values already.

Comment: what would be the possible values for those variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).filter('langTrans', function() {  
  var translate = [{
      'Language 1': {
        'searchsites': 'Job Search', 
        'visitsites': 'View Jobs',
      }
    },
    {
      'Language 2': {
        'searchsites': 'Recherche d emploi',
        'visitsites': 'Voir les offres',
      }
    },
    {
      'Language 3': {
        'searchsites': 'Пошук роботи',
        'visitsites': 'Переглянути роботу',
      }
    }
  ]

  return function(input, language) {
    return translate.filter(function(x){ return !!x[language]; })[0][language][input];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  {{'searchsites' | langTrans : 'Language 3'}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I changed them. But it's not working. No console issues as well. Nothing shows.

Comment: @coderaizer, are you sure? My code, probably, works, you can try it by yourself. May be you forgot quotes?

Comment: In my programme ,there's already a value for searchsites and visitsites.

Comment: Ok, at my case, `temp` variable equals to `'searchsites'` and it works. May be your dictionary, i.e. `data` variable doesn't contain key, which you want to translate?

Comment: Yes, at this case you can return this value without traslation. Look at my answer again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162072/discussion-between-coderaizer-and-slava-utesinov).